# Trouble installing virtualenv on Windows 8 for Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, virtualenv, python-3.4

I'm trying to learn Flask at the moment by following [this tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world)
, but I'm having trouble at the first part where I need to install virtualenv. Here are the steps that I have taken and the results:

1. Edited my PATH to include `D:\Program Files\Python3` and `D:\Program Files\Python3\Scripts`
2. Opened Command Prompt (running it as administrator)
3. Navigated to the directory I want to create my project in
4. Typed `python -m venv flask` and a folder containing flask was created
5. Typed `pip install virtualenv` and here's where the error arose:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "D:\Program Files\Python3\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", mod_spec)
>
> File "D:\Program Files\Python3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals)
>
> File "D:\Program Files\Python3\Scripts\pip.exe__main__.py", line 5, in
>
> ImportError: No module named 'pip'

That seems odd to me, as the path is accurate. I even confirmed this by typing `echo %PATH%` and got these results:

> C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:
>   \Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\Syst
>   em32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Int
>   el(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Man
>   agement Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Component
>   s\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x
>   86)\Skype\Phone\;D:\Program Files\Python3;D:\Program Files\Python3\Scripts

I'm running Python 3.4.3

As you can see by this screenshot, my PATH should be correct:

[image: location of pip]

Comment: While this doesn't address your `PATH` issue, step 5 is unnecessary. `venv` creates your virtual environment. You don't need to use `virtualenv` to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have no idea, I was just following the tutorial.

Comment: The tutorial says you only need to install it for versions of Python prior to 3.4.

Comment: Oh dang, you're right. Sorry I read the instructions wrong!

Comment: Right. And that's step 4. Step 5 says "If you are using any other version of Python older than 3.4, then you need to download and install virtualenv.py before you can create a virtual environment."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

For some reason, `pip install virtualenv` won't work if Python is installed on a drive that is not the C:/ drive. I reinstalled Python to c:/Python34 and tried `pip install virtualenv` again (after changing the PATH) and it worked fine.